# Problem stopping a stepper motor with an endstop

Tags: electronics

Basically I have created the following code to control my stepper motor:

```
int pin_enable_motor_x = 38;
int pin_motor_step_x = A0;
int pin_direction_x = A1;
int endstop_x = 3;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin_enable_motor_x, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_motor_step_x, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_direction_x, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(endstop_x, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(pin_enable_motor_x, LOW);

  for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    runMotorSingleStepX(100, false); // runMotorSingleStepX(int delay, boolean direction)
    if (digitalRead(endstop_x) == true) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

void loop() {

}

void runMotorSingleStepX(int wait, boolean value) { 
  digitalWrite(pin_direction_x, value);
  digitalWrite(pin_motor_step_x, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(wait);
  digitalWrite(pin_motor_step_x, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(wait);
}
```

The idea is that the stepper motor will give many single steps until it reaches my mechanical endstop. But what really happens is that it detects `true` random pulses even when my endstop isn't pressed. So my motor stops before the point it should stop. I'm not sure if it's a common problem and I should be using some tricks to fix this problem.

Does anyone know what could be happening supposing that my electronics circuit is properly settled?

Comment: How is this endstop switch wired exactly?

Comment: I'm controlling a RAMPS board (http://www.reprap.org/wiki/File:RAMPS1.4schematic.png)... It happens with all endstop min (3,14,18) and max (2,15,19) pins... I believe that it's some kind of noise problem that's possible to treat by software because the Marlin firmware ( the official firmware that runs with the Arduino Mega and RAMPS) works fine.

Comment: Try making the endstop mode `INPUT_PULLUP`

Comment: It seems to be a little more stable... But it still stops before the point sometimes.

Comment: Try a stronger pull-up, like 10k. Try a capacitor (eg. 0.1 µF) between the switch pin and ground.

Comment: Thanks, the extra 10K resistor solved the problem :) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer based on comments originally under the question*

It sounds like the endstop switch may have floating input. Try making the endstop pins `INPUT_PULLUP` rather than `INPUT`.

> It seems to be a little more stable... But it still stops before the point sometimes.

Try a stronger pull-up, like 10k. Over a long wiring run the inbuilt 50k pull-up may not be strong enough to counter noise in nearby wires.

> Thanks, the extra 10K resistor solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `for()` loop is using an `int` type for the iterator. You are asking it to run for up to 200,000 steps but an `int` is a 16 bit signed entity (~+/-32,768) so the `for()` loop will exit well before it reaches your desired count. That may be why you are not reaching the stop while still in the loop.

You may want to use an unsigned long as the type for your loop counter and or use a `while()` construct in which you incorporate the exit condition.

Comment: That's true, thanks ... But actually I wasn't using the 200000 max value. I just put a huge number there to make tests. Even fixing the int value my endstop is still detecting random pulses along the way and stopping before my motor reaches it.